Swift Vapor client is not sending Body on Post Request
I am attempting to make a request to an external API in Vapor using a .post() request on the client.
let payload = TwitchTokenPayload(client_id: client_id,
                                 client_secret: client_secret,
                                 grant_type: "client_credentials")

req.client.post("https://id.twitch.tv/oauth2/token", content: payload)

Payload correctly conforms to Content protocol, and yet I am still getting the 400 error back from Twitch saying missing Client Id.
I have set this same request up on Postman and it works.
One thing I noticed, I'm not sure if this is a bug with Vapor, but inside the Client file's send() function, they actually are always passing a nil body.
var request = ClientRequest(method: method, url: url, headers: headers, body: nil, byteBufferAllocator: self.byteBufferAllocator)

I think this may be what is causing the issue. Does anyone have an alternative way to work around this? Or should I just implement a standard HTTP request not using Vapor? This seems like a major issue with this framework if this is the case.

There is another method which should work fine
let payload = TwitchTokenPayload(client_id: client_id,
                                 client_secret: client_secret,
                                 grant_type: "client_credentials")
req.client.post("https://id.twitch.tv/oauth2/token") { req in
    try req.content.encode(payload, as: .json)
}


Thanks! Although I tried this with still no luck
https://github.com/vapor/vapor/issues/3245
You can see the convo I am having on the Vapor repo. It is strange, there seems to be content getting encoded, but it does not flow through to the request body. At least not that I can tell

Closing this as I found that for some reason the .json setting was not sending as json, and instead was being received as plain text. Not sure why. Sending as .urlEncodedForm instead worked
